# two Eloquent model with multiple pivot table

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have two models 'article' and 'user' model, and I want to show more than one M2M relation between them: such as bookmarks, votes, views, ...

I mean I want to have more than one M2M relation for article and user model. I'm pretty stuck as to how to implement this.

Comment: If I understand you well, you need additional fields in pivot table so every article_user relation could have certain amount of bookmarks, votes, views etc. Am I on good track?